# Firebird SQL IF in where

Tags: sql, firebird, firebird2.5

I want to select the amount from products from (stock) shelf1 and shelf 2 but also list items from shelf3 but list amounts of shelf3 as amount = 0.

```
SELECT item, amount 
FROM prodcuts 
WHERE kind = 'bike' 
and (stock = 'shelf1' or stock = 'shelf2' )
```

.

```
Table products
item    kind    stock   amount
cruiser bike    shelf1  1
cruiser bike    shelf2  2
racing  bike    shelf3  4
```

Result is

```
cruiser 3
```

But I need result

```
cruiser 3
racing  0
```

Answer (score 3):

Your result would seem to be:

```
select p.item, sum(case when p.stock = 'shelf3' then 0 else p.amount end)
from products p
group by p.item;
```

I'm not quite sure how this fits in with your explanation, however.

Comment: `stock` => `p.stock`

Comment: note, Firebird supports "iif". It can be simplified as: select p.item, sum(iif(p.stock = 'shelf3', 0, p.amount))

Comment: @Marcodor . . . `case` is ANSI standard.  I don't consider `iif()` to be a "simplification".  I consider it an abomination because it originated in MS Access.

Comment: Yes, it is not in SQL standard, but since the question is about `Firebird` it must be a known thing. Also FB is not alone: MS SQL, Sybase, Access have it. Just a convenient alias for a simple case.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT item, CASE WHEN stock = 'shelf3' THEN 0 ELSE amount END AS amount
FROM prodcuts 
WHERE kind = 'bike' 
and (stock = 'shelf1' or stock = 'shelf2'' or stock = 'shelf3' )
```